getSomeColumn is not a method even using lombok
Below is my database entity
package org.example.api.entidades;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "terceiros")
public class TerceiroEntidade {
    @Id
    private String cnpj_cpf;
    private String nome;
    private String tipo;
    private String estado;
}

Now we have the controller
@PutMapping("/update")
public Object update(@RequestBody TerceiroEntidade terceiro){
    terceiroService.findById(terceiro.getNome());
    return terceiroService.updateTerceiro(terceiro);
}

the problem is I can't use any getters from lombok, terceiro.getNome() returns me an error Cannot resolve method 'getNome' in 'TerceiroEntidade'.

You have no member called column, why do you expect lombok to generate getColumn?

getColumn is a generic representation of i cant get any column value regarding terceiro

that is getNome, getTipo, getEstado, getCnpj_cpf dont work

Is this a compiler error or a runtime exception?

You may get this situation.(no getter and setter)

After setup lombok correctly

Please refer previous answer for Intellij : Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA
Also, we could get generic reference from Setting up Lombok with Eclipse and Intellij
